# TYPO3 6.2 file list icon configuration

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I have a problem with icon configuration on TYPO3 6.2.x file list. Im trying to wrap the whole image code (with `a` tag) into `div` tag, but the only possibility is to wrap the `img` tag (without `a` tag). Here is my configuration:

```
tt_content.uploads.20.renderObj = COA
tt_content.uploads.20.renderObj.15.file {
  import = fileadmin/media/icons/
  import.wrap = |.png
  width = 32
}
tt_content.uploads.20.renderObj.15.wrap = <div class="img">|</div>
```

With this configuration nothing has changed:

```
tt_content.uploads.20.renderObj.10.wrap = <div class="img">|</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to achive that both the icon and the link is wrapped you need to wrap the typolink instead of the image:

```
tt_content.uploads.20.renderObj.15.stdWrap.typolink.wrap = <div class="img">|</div>
```

With this change you have an output like this:

```
<div class="img">
    <a href="fileadmin/user_upload/test.jpg" target="_blank">
       <img src="typo3/gfx/fileicons/jpg.gif" width="18" height="16" alt="" border="0">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: That is what i'm looking for. Thanks :)